# How can I manipulate the OS X file extended attributes (specifically, the color bits) from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos

I would like to use a Ruby script to set the color attribute of files in an OS X directory, e.g., "Set files older than 2 weeks to red." Is this possible in Ruby?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [xattr](http://rubygems.org/gems/xattr) gem.

Comment: Can you give any guidance on reading and writing the bits (in particular, the color bits)? Although xattr.list identifies "com.apple.FinderInfo" a call to get() just returns ""

Comment: Run `xattr -l myfile` in Terminal to see what the com.apple.FinderInfo should be for colors. It looks like just one byte changes.

Comment: I must have a different version of xattr -- I cannot use the -l option. Anyway, one way or the other, the issue seems to be that the xattr gem is returning an empty string for com.apple.FinderInfo.

Comment: Try `xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo myfile`?